# How do I run a shell script and jar application in a docker image?

Tags: docker

How do I run a shell script(not a oneliner rather say 20-30 lines) and jar application in a docker image at the Entrypoint? Looks like I can specify only one EntryPoint?

Comment: You can only specify one entrypoint, but that entrypoint can do whatever you want so not much of a limitation.  Can you show us what you've tried so far?  There are lots of example Docker images out there.

Comment: you can do in your entrypoint `sh myscript.sh ; launch the jar`

Comment: @user2915097 you mean ENTRYPOINT["sh", "myscript.sh", ";", "java", "-jar", "myapplication.jar"]

Comment: yes, it seems correct, did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to add the folder that contains your shell-script and jar application to the Dockerfile.

Suppose you have your shellscript and jar application in a folder app along side Dockerfile. Your directory structure would look something like

$ `ls`
Dockerfile
app
- shell-script.sh
- myapplication.jar

Add the folder `app` to the Dockerfile

`From ubuntu:15.04 # choose right image here add java and other dependencies
ADD app /app
CMD /app/shell-script.sh && java -jar /app/myapplication.jar`

Build the image and run
$ `docker run -it imageName`.

During development, avoid building the docker image everytime you change your script or jar application by mounting the folder at the same place you placed your folder in the Dockerfile and run the container. This will save you a lot of time.

`docker run -it -v $(pwd)/app:/app imageName`

Comment: Note that according to the [Dockerfile Best Practise guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/) you probably want to use `COPY` and not `ADD` unless your situation specifically calls for the latter.